# how to solve int() lireral with base 10 error web.py python

Tags: python, web.py

So when I run this:

```
class query:

    def GET(self, query, page = 1):
        size = 40
        results = es.search(index=conf.es_video_index, body={"size":int(size),
                  "from":int(size)*(int(page)),
                  "query":{
                      "match": {
                          "title": query,
                           }
                       }
                   })
```

I have this error:

```
invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

Could someone explain to me why?

Comment: I cannot spot it down exactly because your example is a little bit vague. 
But i assume that your `page` is not a valid int. Try printing it for debugging. A valid int literal is a decimal number, so neither a float nor a string nor None

Comment: The problem is that passed `page` arg is not a valid integer string

Comment: Please post the call that call `GET()`

Comment: but if page equals 1, that means that page is an integer, so, i dont know where is the problem.

Comment: Please post the complete url of the page that hook you `GET` and the pattern that handle your class: we will found `page` value. Anyway try to print it in `GET`.

Comment: Note: just because your `page` argument has a default value which is a valid int it does NOT mean that you cannot call it with an invalid int literal like e.g. `GET(self, 'hello', 'not an int')`

Answer (score 2):

Now maybe your question is more about *why `page` is not an integer*. I can just guess that your url handling hook is something like this:

```
"/(\w*)/(.*)", "query"
```

In this case `query` class `GET` method take two arguments: the first will be your `query` parameter and the second `page` parameter.

That is just a long shot but if you don't give any information about your url handling and the page url that raise the exception we can just guess where the issue is.

---

If the question is really

> Could someone explain me why?

The answer is because `page` is not a valid integer literal string. That means that it not a `int` or not a string that can be converted to `int`. Follow some Example of what is not a literal strings:

- `'abc'`
- `'1.2'`
- `None`
- every object `o` where `str(o)` is not a valid literal integer

I take in account just `page` because `size` is already an integer and `int(size)` cannot raise any exception.